# Incorrect "edit" link tooltip on per site metas

Tags: bug, edits, per-site-meta, wording

If you try and edit a Meta post on a site where you don't have the Edit Anywhere privilege, you get this message:

[image]

It should actually read non *community* wiki.

Answer (score 1):

Huh? Suggested edits can only be made on tag wikis on per-site metas. You gain the ability to edit community wiki posts at 100 reputation, which occurs instantly for anyone with 200 reputation on a linked SE account.

Comment: In that case I'm still not sure why it's referring to suggested edits; most people don't know WTF a tag wiki is and they're not really "posts" as otherwise defined by the system (post= question/answer). It makes much more sense to say "suggested edits are not allowed on meta questions/answers". The tag wiki bit is just something extra to be confused about

Comment: WTH do tag-wikis have to do with non-community posts?

Comment: @BenBrocka Exactly! I asked a question [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147972/suggested-edits-are-not-allowed-for-non-tag-wiki-posts-on-meta-sites) (now closed) too. They should really remove the tag-wiki part

Comment: On meta sites without the editing privilege, you can not even suggest edits on any non CW posts.  I think that the tooltip is therefore indeed incorrect.

Comment: @Rory: *"Suggested edits are **not allowed** on **non-tag-wiki** posts."* - It makes no mention of any other type of post. That statements simply means you can *only* suggest edits on *tag wikis*. A question or answer, whether CW or not, is *not a tag wiki*.

Comment: @animuson Ohh I'm with you now, it still seems an odd message to display when you're no where near the tag-wiki at the time though